# Fuse type/fn pairs into polymorphic fn via 'anonymous' protocol & method

Tags: clojure

My goal is a function/macro that works like this:

```
(def f (polymorphic-fn
          java.lang.Long   (fn [a] (inc a))
          java.lang.String (fn [a] (str a "x"))))
(f 1)     ;; => 2
(f "abc") ;; => "abcx"
```

Since the type-based dispatch of protocols has the best performance I was thinking to create an 'anonymous' protocol for the 'fused' function with a macro like this:

```
(defmacro polymorphic-fn
  [& pairs]
  (let [proto  (gensym)
        method (gensym)
        extends (for [[type handler] pairs]
                  `(extend ~type ~proto {(keyword ~method) ~handler}))]
    `(do
       (defprotocol ~proto (~method [e#]))
       ~@extends
       ~method)))
```

This produces the error: `Unable to resolve symbol: G__18707`.

Is there a way to return the 'anonymous' method, or is there a better way to implement such a function?

Comment: well the ultimate goal is a library for abstracting over various recursion schemes, so the dispatch mechanism is pretty critical and multimethods aren't great in that regard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `defprotocol` will *generate* code that will intern the protocol methods. Ie. after macroexpansion, the symbols for your defined method is still not known to the compiler. Thus, the *compilation* fails and will barf that the symbol is unknown.

Many other `def...`'s will generate a macro "call" that will intern the symbol during macro expansion (and thus the compiler will remain happy).

To fix it you can just declare it beforehand. This works since `declare` is macro, will get expanded and the compiler will be happy:

```
(defmacro polymorphic-fn
  [& pairs]
  (let [proto (gensym "proto")
        method (gensym "prot-method-")
        extends (for [[type handler] (partition 2 pairs)]
                  `(extend ~type ~proto {~(keyword (str method)) ~handler}))]
    `(do
       (declare ~method)
       (defprotocol ~proto (~method [e#]))
       ~@extends
       ~method)))
```

Note: I also fixed the `keyword` call in this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want to use regular protocols, along with `extend-type`:

```
(defprotocol Fooable
  (foo [this]) )
(extend-type java.lang.Long
  Fooable
  (foo [some-long] (inc some-long)))
(extend-type java.lang.String
  Fooable
  (foo [any-string] (str any-string "-and-more")))
```

with result:

```
(foo 3)        => 4
(foo "hello")  => "hello-and-more"
```

It may be possible to use a macro to hide the protocol name by using an auto-gensym, but I don't see the point.  Just ignore the protocol name 'Fooable' and you have the same result.

Also, be aware that parts of Clojure implementation create concrete Java classes behind the scenes, which may require a hard-coded name.

You could also mimic the protocol functionality by using a `cond`:

```
(defn bar [it]
  (cond
    (= (class it) java.lang.Long) (inc it)
    (= (class it) java.lang.String) (str it "-and-more")))

(bar 7)            => 8
(bar "farewell")   => "farewell-and-more"
```

You could define a function to generate `bar` like you do with `polymorphic-fn` if you wanted.

Comment: `polymorphic-fn` is just a building block for higher-level library functions and part of the purpose is to get rid of boilerplate. the other big factor is performance and the cond is nowhere near the type-based dispatch of protocols